# SFSafariViewController doesn't work in portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying out the new SFSafariViewController on an iPad Pro in a simulator. It works in landscape but not portrait.  Here's my code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://forums.greenrobot.com"]];
if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
    //SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]initWithURL:URL entersReaderIfAvailable:YES];

    [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

[image: Working in Landscape]
[image: Not working portrait]

Comment: Me too. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: Im just launching safari now and not too happy about it.